# Rearrange the result by ordering (Python 2.7.15)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to rearrange the row by ordering.

if "MCS7" changes to "MCS11" as below list,
How will you code?

```
list = [['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.02', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-32.08', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.98', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '763.52', 'Hz', 'PASS']]
for l in sorted(list, key = lambda x: ( x[4], x[5] ) ):
    print l
```

I expect the output that as below, by ordering "MCS5~MCS11".

```
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS']]
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.02', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-32.08', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.98', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '763.52', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS11', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to sort your list based on one element of your inner lists. A
 similar questions (using list tuples are is asked here: [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples) )

You can use the [`key` paramter of `sort()`/`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) and a lambda or 
 8operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for it :

```
data = [
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.02', 'dBm', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-32.08', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.98', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.56', 'dB', 'PASS'],
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '763.52', 'Hz', 'PASS']]

# sort by 5th value and 6th value so that same 5th are alphabetically sorted
for l in sorted(data, key = lambda x: ( x[4], x[5] ) ):
    print l
```

Output:

```
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS5', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.02', 'dBm', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '763.52', 'Hz', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-32.08', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.98', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS']
```

Read more about sorting:

- [2.7/howto/sorting](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html) and
- [key-functions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

About lambda: [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

---

To sort by the "pure" numerical value, use:

```
for l in sorted(data, key = lambda x: ( int(x[4][3:]) , x[5]) ):
    print l
```

The part

```
int(x[4][3:])
```

strips away "MCS" by slicing and converts the remainder to an integer as first part of the tuple.

Comment: Dear Patrick, if "MCS7" changes to "MCS11", there are "MCS5", "MCS6" and "MCS11". How will you change the coding? Because actual re-arrangement will "MCS11", "MCS5", "MCS6".

Comment: A new issue if "MCS7" changes to "11Mbps", "MCS6" changes to "5.5Mbps", and "MCS6" changes to "1Mbps", how will you code?

Comment: How would you? I am not providing answers to every follow up question you got. In software development processes this is called [feature or scope creep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447344/). You do the same as for integers: you find a way to split the data you want how you want it and then make it a number (int/float) - you can write a small helper function for that and apply it  `(helper(x[4]),x[5])` instead of  `( int(x[4][3:]) , x[5])`. In your case your helper could remove all Letters from the string - unless you also got `'34Evil14Things2Do'`  => `34142`

Comment: Sorry for further specific issue that makes you unhappy since I thought you may have clever way to sort "11Mbps,5.5Mbps,1Mbps". As your final words, I've tried remove all letters from string. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Patrick, 
On "11Mbps,5.5Mbps,1Mbps" condition,
I try the code without remove string just for your reference as below,
and thanks for your suggestion key function, "lambda".

for l in sorted(data, key = lambda x: ( int(x[3]) , eval(x[4].split('M')[0]))):
    print l